# Excel - matching 2 cells from one sheet in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I am trying to work out a formula that says if one cell in a sheet, and another cell in the same sheet match the same names of cells in a different sheet, then the answer is a cell between those sheets.

I've tried MATCH and INDEX but can't seem to get it to work. Is anyone able to assist?

Cheers

Comment: show an example of sheets and desired output. Someone will help you...

Comment: I have a list a produce along the rows, and a list of restaurants in the colums, and then when a restaurant has a particular request for a particular produce item, there is the request in-between.

On another sheet, I have a column for restaurants and a column for produce items. I'd like the next cell to spit out the "request" when restaurant and item come up.

Comment: Can you post the formula you tried with index/match?  And some sample data would be helpful too.  and "....an answer between those sheets", what does that mean? Like literally, if you look at your workbook, the sheets go "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", so if a value in sheet1 *and* sheet3 match, you want something from Sheet2 returned?